# Need understanding of how log4j appender works

Tags: java, log4j

I have a simple log4j HelloWorld program..

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("pre_loggerDOTinfo");
        logger.info("Hello, World!mmm");
        System.out.println("post_loggerDOTinfo");
    }
}
```

Here is my properties file, which I put in the same directory :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\Users\adel\Desktop\Misc_Stuff\Java_Code\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

But for some reason, I do not find a logging file being created in the same directory. I was thinking that after I run the program, it creates the file `logging.log`

Comment: Does it work if you give the path as "C:/Users/adel/Desktop/Misc_Stuff/Java_Code/logging.log"

Comment: @AndyDufresne - no , this didn't work.  hmm , not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash is an escape character in properties files, so if you want to specify the file name

```
C:\Users\adel\Desktop\Misc_Stuff\Java_Code\logging.log
```

then you need to double the backslashes:

```
C:\\Users\\adel\\Desktop\\Misc_Stuff\\Java_Code\\logging.log
```

Or alternatively, use forward instead of backward slashes (`C:/Users/...`) as windows can cope with either. The properties parser reacts to unrecognised escape sequences by silently ignoring the backslash, so it will see your original value as

```
C:UsersadelDesktopMisc_StuffJava_Codelogging.log
```

You may find it has created a file with that very long name in whatever was the current directory on your C: drive when you started the Java process.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it's still not working , but I'm on the right track and will keep at it, thanks !!!